# Failed To Install Gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine

I am using RubyMine and attempting to setup a solution for the first time.

When I open the project, it says

```
RubyMine Gem Manager
           RubyMine has detected that
           some of the gems required for 'features'
           are not installed
           Install missing gems
           (show balloon)
```

When I try to install it, it 'searches gem repositories' and then pops up with an error:

```
Following gems were not installed:
mauth-client: No Gem satisfying dependency found in remote gem repositories
```

The thing is, this doesn't make sense from the begining. If I type 'bundle show mauth-client' from the same directory that I have open in RubyMine, it gives the location in the /bundler/gems folder of where this gem is located.

Why is this error appearing and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Add your `Gemfile` to the question. If the source is rubygems it´s because https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=mauth-client

Answer (score 0):

The gem isn't being found in the default gem source, RubyGems.org. I did a quick Google search and I wasn't able to find the `mauth-client` gem, so its likely that its in a private gem repository.

If you end up finding the gem source, add a line like this to the top of your Gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

Obviously, replacing https://rubygems.org with the URL to your gem repository.